# A bit confused on p values on ttest in Stata output

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, assumptions, association-measure

In Stata the output of a ttest shows p values as:

```
Pr(T<t), Pr(|T|>|t|) and Pr(T>t)
```

I understand the two sides to be the tails of the test and the middle to be probability that there is no difference.

If I have data in which I have a clinical suspicion that the mean of x is greater than the mean of y, can I use `Pr(T>t)` in a report or is there a "rule" that only `Pr(|T|>|t|)` should be used to report p-values from t-tests?

Comment: The middle Pr(|T|>|t|) gives you the two sided probability. You are looking for the one sided probability where T > t. There are no rules in which of the two sided or one sided you report. You just have to be clear on which one you are stating.

Comment: Some areas that use statistics are much less likely to accept one-sided tests than others; this is in many cases perhaps less a statistical issue than a cultural difference.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open. It has nothing specifically to do with Stata and is about one-tailed vs. two-tailed tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if that is your alternative hypothesis:

> I have data in which I have a clinical suspicion that the mean of x is greater than the mean of y

then you can use a one-tailed test. If it is going to be part of a paper for publication then you should perhaps consult the journal's guidelines since it might require a two-sided test. In any case, just be very clear about what you are doing and why.